# Will python collect the memory allocated in the shared memory by using multiprocessing.sharedctypes?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, multiprocessing

I use multiprocessing.sharedctypes.Array() to allocate a shared memory to do multiprocessing. However, when the programs runs, I observe that the kernel_task takes a lot of memory (like 9GB) and the swap memory is increasing. So I wonder will python collect the memory allocated in the shared memory automatically ?

Also, I checked the code of multiprocessing.heap, it do have malloc() and free(). But in the sharedctype s.py, it only calls the malloc().

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution. I use multiprocess.Pool.map to do multiprocessing in a function like this:

```
def gemm():
    pool = multiprocess.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(some_fun,arg_list)

for i in xrange(10):
    gemm()
```

However, I forget to add the pool.close() and pool.join() after pool.map. So every time I call gemm, it will cost some memory. Pool won't release its resources even the reference count is zero. 
The correct thing to do is add pool.close() and pool.join():

```
def gemm():
    pool = multiprocess.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(some_fun,arg_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

for i in xrange(10):
    gemm()
```

I am still not sure what's the exact reason why pool won't release its resource, but this is the solution.

Comment: You could also do: `def gemm(): with Pool(4) as p: p.map(..)` to avoid needing the explicit cleanup. But either way, this answer seems to fix your memory leak without answering your original question, when do `sharedctypes` actually get released?